# Is it Possible to use reflection on LINQ to Entities to query a dynamic table?

Tags: linq, reflection

There are many tables in the database that are used as "lookup" tables.  All the tables have the same structure, other than the ID column name.

I have found that I can use reflection to open a table and enumerate through the records.  The method takes a string (tableName).

```
Uri serviceUri = new Uri("http://localhost/MyDataService/WcfDataService.svc");
var context = new MyEntities(serviceUri);
var eTable = typeof(MyEntities).GetProperty(tableName).GetValue(context, null) as IEnumerable<object>
foreach (object o in eTable)
...
```

This works fine, but I want to add a WHERE clause to the query.  For example, where InactiveDate == null.

Can I do this?  I have been unable to figure this one out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
var eTable = (typeof(MyEntities).GetProperty(tableName).GetValue(context, null) as IEnumerable<object>).Where(obj => obj.GetType().GetProperty("InactiveDate").GetValue(obj) == null);
foreach (object o in eTable)
```

Comment: This fetches all records and filters on the client.

Comment: Unbelievable.  I could slap myself for not figuring that out!  This will work for the lookup tables, exactly what I need.  I know it's not the best solution as I'd rather the filter be applied on the server as part of the query.  Is there a way create a query without knowing the table name in advance?

Comment: I would then try not to cast the queriable collection to IEnumerable<object> but to IQueryable<object> and then to Where method you need to pass an Expression object which will be then converted to uri. To create Expression you may use Expression static class. I did such a thing for DbContext, should work for DataServiceContext as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use generics and maybe an interface over reflection.

```
public function Xyz<TEntity>(Func<MyEntities, IDbSet<TEntity>> dbSetGetter, Expression<Func<TEntity, Boolean>> filter)
{
   var serviceUri = new Uri("http://localhost/MyDataService/WcfDataService.svc");

   using (var context = new MyEntities(serviceUri))
   {
      foreach (var entity in dbSetGetter(context).Where(filter))
      {
         DoSomethingWith(entity);
      }
   }
}
```

Usage would be like this

```
Xyz(context => context.Foo, foo => foo.Bar == 42);
```

assuming you have an entity `Foo` with an integer property `Bar`. The obvious difference to your code is that you have to know the entity type a compile time and I am not sure if you know it then.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel.  This is good, but I don't know which table is being requested.  Very good for me to keep as a future reference, though.